# What are the difference in obfuscated contract laws between Indonesia and USA, Australia, Europe, and Singapore?

Tags: criminal-law, contract-law, civil-law, consumer-protection, indonesia

In general, people can write any contract they want. In practice, many people agree to a contract without even reading. Even those that read carefully may miss important terms if the writers of the contract obfuscate the terms deliberately. Some scammy sellers often obfuscate some part of the contracts to make really bad deals look good.

Some samples:

1. https://www.tnp.sg/news/sim-lim-squares-phone-scam-makes-headlines-internationally Here a seller in Sim Lim writes $1000 fee as $36 x 24. Many buyers end up paying $2k for an iPhone that usually worth $1k
2. In United States, people sell Acai Berry. https://www.nbcnews.com/id/wbna38958053 Basically, people sign up for a cheap free trial not realizing that they end up subscribing to hundreds of dollars cost of products that are not working
3. In Indonesia, mixing insurance and investment can be very dangerous. That's because the fee can be 100 times bigger than normal. The fee is obfuscated even more than the Sim Lim scam. No normal person can know such fee without being told. The companies have agents that supposedly "explain" the fee. However, it seems that most agents do not tell about the fees and instead lie or mislead customers by claiming that all money are invested. https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.kaskus.co.id%2Fthread%2F5c715f134601cf268b08e4b1%2Fbeli-asuransi-di-avrist-biaya-100-kali-lipat-sampai-sekarang-masalah-belum-jelas%2F

If we follow strict standard contract policy, the customer is at fault for not reading the contract carefully.

However, I noticed that in US and Singapore such scammy contracts are punished. FTC screw acai berry scams. Sim Lim scammers are jailed.

Yet in Indonesia, large corporations keep selling their ridiculously overpriced products counting on customers not knowing about their hidden fees.

So how come Indonesia is different? Are scamming by obfuscating contracts common too in US and Singapore?

What are the difference in the laws, between Indonesia, Singapore, and US, that may explain why such scams happen in Indonesia and done by large companies?

Some of the thing that may be the case are

1. In Indonesia, truth is not a defense against defamation. Also defamation can be a criminal case instead of just civil.
2. Prosecuting anyone for fraud is extremely difficult in Indonesia
3. Maybe there isn't really any differences. Similar scams exist in other countries too.
4. I've heard in US there are rules that 80% of money must be used for reimbursement. Is this true?

So what are the differences?

Comment: Indonesia and all the other countries? There are 195 of them!

Comment: Australia, Singapore, US. Some of the advance ones where things like this are not happening

Comment: Insurance law is *state matter* in the US. So you have 50 frameworks for in-state insurance, and add some interstate federal framework... makes 51 applicable laws in the us alone

Comment: I will update the question

Comment: @user4951 Can you cite a source for your claim that "most people agree to a contract without even reading" please.

Comment: Do you read term of service @RickApe?

Comment: https://www.businessinsider.com/deloitte-study-91-percent-agree-terms-of-service-without-reading-2017-11?r=US&IR=T again, the issue is to people not reading contract. The issue is companies deliberately obfuscate contract so that even those who read it will miss imporotant terms. The company give deals that are so bad that if people know they most likely don't buy

Comment: For example, that sim lim iphone. He sold iPhone at $1000 and sell additional warranty for another $1k. We know that most people will not want to spend another $1k for warranty. So they wrote $36 per month and time $24 it's $1000. The sellers hide the x button. In Indonesia it's even more obfuscated. An insurance agent told me that there is no way a customer can know about acquisition fee unless the agent tell. It's written as some percentage of premi and the amount of premi is written in other pages. The price is 100 times of normal price.

Comment: Contracts are like smart contracts. The difference is, smart contracts often have bugs. Contracts are often fill with deception. How people abuse bugs is why ethereum split from ethereum classic. We basically need people to point out the important part of deceptive contracts.

Comment: Your assertion that "in US . . . such scammy contracts are punished" is a vast overstatement. While there are specific instances (often under state specific laws) where there are punishments, the vast majority of scammy contracts are not punished and are often enforced by courts. Also, a vast array of different kind of legal regimes out there regulate particular kinds of practices, as opposed to this being governed mostly by one or two overarching legal principles. Some industries are regulated (often at a state or local not federal level), other very specific practices are prohibited.

Comment: @RockApe "Can you cite a source for your claim that "most people agree to a contract without even reading"" This is very well established. See, e.g., https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-322-81426-5_10 and https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2017/mar/03/terms-of-service-online-contracts-fine-print and https://www.jstor.org/stable/24246723?seq=1 and https://www.jstor.org/stable/41474940?seq=1

Comment: So Indonesia law is like US laws?

Comment: The concern I am talking about is not a mere user not reading the contract. Here, the company deliberately inserts abusive terms in the contract so that users that read the contract carefully will still most likely not found the hidden large fees. The company usually employs an insurance agent that simply said all money is invested and then blames the customer for not reading the contract carefully or the insurance agent for not explaining clearly. However, the company itself knows what's going on. If asked in public they never want to confirm or deny the existence of the big fee.

Comment: @ohwileke, do you have samples where a contract in US is scammy and uphold in court anyway? Misleading, scammy, but uphold in court.

Comment: @user4951 This is what usually happens. Everything else is an exception. For example, almost all time share contacts and almost all extended warranty contracts and almost all payday loans and almost all non-purchase money car title loans and almost all credit monitoring contracts are scammy. Most bottled water sales is scammy. Lots of diet plans are scammy. Lots of health insurance policies are scammy. Lots of checking accounts have scammy fees. But they are all routinely upheld and enforced.

Comment: But the timeshare contract, payday loan, has clear terms. Any timeshare buyers know that they share property and pay. In Avrist case, and in most insurance terms, the terms are deliberately obfuscated. Do you have samples where a contract is like Sim Lim square. So there is huge substantial unconscionability, and those substantial unconscionability is deliberately obfuscated.

Comment: I wonder if there are laws where such terms with substantial unconscionability must be stated clearly or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this

[Do US or Australia have laws that prevent insurance companies from racking up too much margin?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/58815/do-us-or-australia-have-laws-that-prevent-insurance-companies-from-racking-up-to)

> It is flat out against the law to mislead or deceive - you can’t lie,
> you can’t conceal salient facts, you can’t tell half truths, you can’t
> even tell the truth, the whole truth and nothing but the truth if that
> could be misleading.

So it seems that there is a big different in laws between Australia and Indonesia. Most Indonesian lawyers will simply say that it's customers' fault to not read the contract carefully even if the contract is written with deceptive intent